# Formar un nuevo numero con los dígitos(números) pares de un numero introducido

Tags: c#, vb.net

int cant;
int co=0;

```
        Console.Write("Ingrese la cantidad de elementos: ");
        cant = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] numero = new int[cant];
        int[] numPar=new int [cant];
        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("ingrese el elemento: " + (i + 1) + " : ---->  ");
            numero[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (numero[i] % 2 == 0)
            { 
                
                numPar[i] = numero[i];
                co++;
            }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < cant; i++)//for2
        { 

            Console.WriteLine(numPar[i]);  

        }

       
    
             
        Console.ReadLine();
```

/*el problema es que me muestra los números pares en su posición y en las otras posiciones me muestra 0.
ejemplo: ingreso {1 2 3 4 5} y me devuelve en pantalla {0 2 0 4 0} cuando deberia devolver solo
{2 4} formando así el numero 24.*/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás utilizando el mismo índice para ambos arrays.

Cambia `numPar[i] = numero[i]` por `numPar[co] = numero[i]`